# Checking clicks against MouseButtons.Right

Tags: c#, onmouseclick

In a mouseclick handler, is the correct way to know whether to show a context menu to check the event's `Button` property against `MouseButtons.Right`? If so, wouldn't there be a problem when a (probably left-handed) user tries to use your application with the mouse buttons reversed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it won't be a problem if mouse buttons are reversed.

Lets says I have reversed my mouse buttons, so when I press left mouse button, Windows will raise event for `MouseButtons.Right` and similarly `MouseButtons.Left` when right button is pressed.